# Groetzsch Graph planarity

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

(1) Prove that the Groetzsch Graph is not planar.

Comment: 4-colour-theory is difficult, 2-coour theory is easy.

Comment: ad (2): One cannot colour the faces of a cube with two colours only!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1) recall that a graph is non-planar if and only if it contains a subgraph that is a subdivision of either $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. So can you find such a subgraph? (Hint: $K_5$ works for this case).

Something seems to be wrong with (2). Consider three "countries" where each two share a border (e.g., Oregon, Nevada and California). You clearly need three colors.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more for 1?
I feel like my professor expected an algebraic proof, which I didn't do unfortunately.

And yeah, I think he made a mistake with question 2.

Comment: @Jay C Oh ok. Well one thing that follows from Euler's formula are upper bounds on the number of edges in terms of the number of vertices. Try one of these.